# How to find default clipboard in debian-mate?

Tags: debian, clipboard, mate-desktop

I have 2-3 desktop environments peacefully co-existing with each other with debian-mate being the main environment I work/use with. Any way to know what the default clipboard is ? How do I find it ? This is in relation to an earlier [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337006/for-how-long-does-a-string-remain-in-clipboard-copy-buffer-and-can-it-be-manip) hence unless I know I can't share that info. ?